# VisualSVN post-commit hook failed

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-checkout, post-commit-hook

I try to add a post-commit hook to my VisualSVN Server.
After a commit i need to checkout the whole project.

I do the following in the commit-hook:

`"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\svn.exe" checkout http://Server.local.myServer:82/svn/Project/ D:/Projects/xampp/htdocs/Data/Project/Data --non-interactive --force --username Administrator --password xxx`

If i write this in my CMD, it work's very well. But if I commit my project in my client program, I get always the same error:

`Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
svn: E720005: Error resolving case of 'D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\Data\Project\Data'`

What can i do :( ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe it helps http://www.tomred.net/tutorials/tomred-svn-error-resolving-case.html

Comment: Thanks .. but now another error appears: Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output: svn: E720005: Can't make directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\Projekt': Zugriff verweigert

Now i use: file:///d:/....

Comment: Anybody a solution ? :(

Answer (score 1):

**Unconditional checkout** in post-commit hook is, in common, Bad Idea:

- Commit happens for than once
- Checkout is 1) one-time operation 2) for empty target and will fail (AFAICR) for existing Working Copy as target for checkout

In order to do not overload post-commit hook with logic (but you can implement it "if folder is WC - update, in not - checkout") I'll suggest:

- Checkout WC by hand
- in hook perform `svn up` for WC only